Calculate and plot gradient for every Nth value in array
Is it possible to use np.gradient to calculate the gradient of every 10th value in a given array?
rand = np.random.randint(low=1, high=10, size=(100,))

NOTE: I would like to calculate the gradient twice. Once between every value and once between every 10th value. I would then like to plot both. The 10 values should appear at every tenth position. This is why I can't seem to extract the values at the beginning.

Calculate gradiebt between every value first
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

rand = np.random.randint(low=1, high=10, size=(100,))
gradient_full = np.gradient(rand)

Calculate gradient between every 10th value
rand_10th = rand[::10]
gradient_10th = np.gradient(rand_10th)

create plot
x_full = np.arange(100)
x_10th = np.arange(0, 100, 10)

Plot
plt.figure(figsize=(12, 6))

plt.plot(x_full, gradient_full, label='Gradient (every value)', alpha=0.7)
plt.plot(x_10th, gradient_10th, 'ro-', label='Gradient (every 10th value)', markersize=8)

plt.xlabel('Index')
plt.ylabel('Gradient')
plt.title('Comparison of Gradients')
plt.legend()
plt.grid(True)

plt.show()

output

